# Getting specific image thumbnail urls of attached images

Tags: thumbnails

I am using the [Manual Image Crop](https://wordpress.org/plugins/manual-image-crop/) plugin to set thumbnails for images. I am not using any images as 'featured images' however.

I have a number of thumbnails saved to each image. If I use `wp_get_attachment_link(id, 'medium');` then I get the desired 'medium' thumbnail returned but as whole html block output, including '' tags, size etc etc.

I just want the URL of this specific thumbnail (or the img tags 'src' attribute). Is there a built in wordpress function for this or will I have to use PHP regex or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [wp_get_attachment_image_src](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)

```
<?php 
$attachment_id = 8; // attachment ID

$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'medium' ); // returns an array
if( $image_attributes ) {
?> 
<img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src#Default_Usage

Comment: this only seems to get the 150x150 thumbnail src

Comment: I don't want to be rude but if you hadn't just copied the code but would have had just a short little look at the links provided you would have seen that there is a second parameter for the size. Anyway - I updated the code.

Comment: I do apologise, I must have read an incorrect browser tab half asleep. This is the exact function I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the `$id = 7` for example

and you have `$size = ...;` choose the size you want

use `wp_get_attachment_image_url($id, $size)`